# EOS transaction using MetaMask went wrong. Is it possible to verify transaction within blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

Yesterday I traded 2 ETH on eos.io using MetaMask. I got most of the way through the transaction and was offered the EOS tokens I bought.  I got to the point of the transaction where I had to generate a public/private key and register.  Complications and my unfamiliarity with the micropayment on the blockchain (within the MetaMask app) caused the transaction to fail and I lost the ability to see the EOS I was given.  Basically, in two attempts I was able to generate two sets of public/private keys, but was not successful in registering.  I am afraid that the EOS I purchased are no longer available to me.

I took a number of documenting screen shots of the transaction so I would have as much record as possible, including the exact time and date of the transaction and various addresses and numbers.

Is there any blockchain process by which I can still prove I purchased these EOS tokens and get them back?

I would gladly pay for someone to assist me in this and with a future EOS transaction I want to do without error.
Can someone please help?

Thanks

DS Ramirez

Answer (score 1):

If your transactions were actually completed, and you have your private/public keys, then you still have all your eos tokens.

> Is there any blockchain process by which I can still prove I purchased
>   these EOS tokens and get them back?

The 'blockchain process' you're looking for is literally just what a blockchain is.  Your keys are the wallet, MetaMask is just a piece of software that visualizes this.

If you're not sure whether your transactions was actually sent, the first thing I'd recommend is checking your address(es) on etherscan.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It helped me understand blockchain a bit better.   But one thing I still don't quite get is why the EOS Token Distribution page on eos.io generated two distinct pairs of public/private keys, a pair each time I clicked the GENERATE KEY button.  Why would it do that?  Does it generate keys every time you click it?  Even when 0.000 EOS was showing in the Token Balances space, which is what happened?  (some good news is- my 526 tokens showed up on that page when I opened it again this evening. I didn't expect that.  But now I don't know what the safe next step is.)